# Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value despite conditional binding

Tags: ios, swift

So I have the following lines:

```
let theUsername = "\(String(describing: selectedPost?.user.username!))"

if selectedPost?.user.username! != nil {
    print("Contains a value!")
    username.text = theUsername//Fails here 
} else {
    print("Doesn’t contain a value.")
    username.text = "No username found: Weird"
}
```

The error message:

> Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

would make one think the value inside is nil. However when printing:

```
print("\(String(describing: selectedPost?.user.username!))", " LIT555")
```

I get:

> Optional("C22AE009-8CC6-490A-9328-23A08AAD3A10")  LIT555

How can I turn the value into a non optional (ie. get rid of the Optional() part), so it can work without it failing?

Comment: You still have a force unwrap there - The ! at the end.  This will cause a crash if `username` is `nil` even if `selectedPost` isn't.  You need to conditionally unwrap everything - e.g. `if let post = selectedPost, let username = post.user.username { ..`

Comment: There's no conditional binding in the code you posted.

Comment: And never use `String(describing:)` for anything other than debug output. Never use it to show a value to a user.

Comment: @rmaddy why is that?

Comment: Because its result isn't documented and it does things like add `Optional(...)` to the text. You don't want to show that to a user. Properly deal with optionals instead of doing inappropriate things like string interpolation of `String(describing:)`.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, this has been the root of so many problems... Thanks I will remember this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if let res = selectedPost?.user.username { // to unwrap the optional value 
  // check textfield is not nil
    username.text = res
}
else {
    username.text = "default"
}
```

Or shortly

```
username.text = selectedPost?.user.username ?? "default"
```

According to the crash your textfield is nil , check the IB connection

---

When you do this

```
var selectedPost : Post? { didSet { getMediaStats() loadP3Data() } }
```

and assign a value to `selectedPost` in the `prepare` method of the previous vc , the destination vc outlets are still nil because it's not loaded yet and since `didSet` is called instantly before the load , hence the crash

So remove `didSet` and call what inside it in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: It is connected just checked. I still get Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. Despite res holding a value...

Comment: Before the if statement try `print(username.text)` check whether it'll crash or not

Comment: username.text = selectedPost?.user.username ?? "default" yielded the same error. And the print statement outputted : Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Then there is no way your username outlet isn't connected , make sure it's connected in that vc , try to disconnect and reconnect to that active vc , may be you assign the vc to many scenes

Comment: I updated teh question. I will also do what you just recommended

Comment: if not worked , show how do you instantiate that vc

Comment: I reconnected and same thing happened I will try recreating it.

Comment: I segue to this class using a prepare method to transfer over data like userID and the Post object

Comment: inside of the Phase3VC class is where I write the above code.

Comment: the function `viewDidLoad` ?? or what

Comment: No inside a method : loadP3Data(), which is called in:    var selectedPost : Post? {
        didSet {
            getMediaStats()
            loadP3Data()
        }
    } .

Answer (score 1):

Even thought you're using `!` at the `username`, this expression is still optional because you have the `?` in `selectedPost`. I strongly suggest you to never use forced unwraps (`!`), always use `if let` or `guard let` to make sure you can unwrap an optional and avoid those crashes.

This is what your code could look like:

```
if let theUsername = selectedPost?.user.username {
    username.text = theUsername
} else {
    username.text = "No username found: Weird"
}
```

or

```
username.text = selectedPost?.user.username ?? "No username found: Weird"
```